# dkim=neutral (bad service type)

Tags: gmail, dkim

I am trying to set up the dkim for an email and I am getting this error message on gmail:
dkim=neutral (bad service type).
However on Hotmail it is passing. I have not found any information on this error message, so any advice would be helpful.

Here is the Original Message:

```
Delivered-To: TESTING@gmail.com
Received: by 2002:a2e:5854:0:0:0:0:0 with SMTP id x20-v6csp893645ljd;
        Wed, 8 Aug 2018 08:07:45 -0700 (PDT)
X-Google-Smtp-Source: AA+uWPwCsAoSTliFFu3I4cBtvNV8CvibawSIWTWiElYkASdt3RQ47cI0CIJaV6vr0GWys6s/3Jt6
X-Received: by 2002:a24:8b82:: with SMTP id g124-v6mr2798782ite.70.1533740864216;
        Wed, 08 Aug 2018 08:07:44 -0700 (PDT)
ARC-Seal: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; t=1533740864; cv=none;
        d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        b=1BsJJ1Sj/HbLQ3PNoOa/t0OHMwjAXAkj4cij3n9ffX1tlY1GLPM6r9f42wEyB32ITM
         f8yELMvZU32AGgjVW7YHIa4RZbzYLLko6rNQAn3bidcXpXJaxyOFv1ash4TBQPCDqK42
         yiUgmPnkWmiwl0vzQ1EwvJh8XgyKiVN6z4JZwmfiKgfGXhO2owB1zyFma9pqDAs6x8Rr
         AxXGBlS7qS7MEeZVi5MOhUK/vHVZsgiT28HPta6B8t424XbY0nK52SeBCBbsVcJ3uQPq
         3kSpT82xnlQnh/xahyvOvhzgW+6keyQVxflTM2AQSfAGmMh5zAWi7UzTkg99C8o3Wy0S
         oP0A==
ARC-Message-Signature: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        h=to:from:subject:date:content-transfer-encoding:content-disposition
         :mime-version:message-id:dkim-signature:arc-authentication-results;
        bh=kyJ1zj8ga4Rrouj1cYjnkFyoRvpab2ORo/JsFPpGPeg=;
        b=wA6sRXpfHwSBPs8+7ozPKKs06+ncqHEAI8WZABiet5HjZFTAKVKbvHXNcJHmQZrYya
         fi94H9xuxscn5VvKxA/krnmeFxHtWI+CZVzDlAh5oAr26wJDJF4VYBtf7s9E+J4fNJ+C
         bIsnmApRPH+JCA6FrRF4yOy6MVBDohs2F+N07xx9weKju0zobunG3x7MWcUQN3OUMWp4
         uDsRZsiU2nn0kpujtXCRGls7atOUrRkR7Eyl9705035Lg9jJrAOP9Gvci7/sxP9pTTaF
         8JtKaQre0BCfEbP4iguHco3ruRBgWh9Jn9a9cH1jy4MkZTbb/a8WEz7CoV0JP3cLMar9
         9xOw==
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com;
       dkim=neutral (bad service type) header.i=@libertycreativesolutions.com
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Disposition: inline
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-Type: text/html
X-Mailer: MIME::Lite 3.027 (F2.77; T1.28; A2.04; B3.14; Q3.13)
Date: Wed, 8 Aug 2018 10:07:42 -0500
Subject: testing 
From: TESTING@libertycreativesolutions.com
To: TESTING@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `s=libertycreativesolutions;` in your DNS entry for `libertycreativesolutions._domainkey.libertycreativesolutions.com` which looks like below.

```
text = "v=DKIM1; g=*; d=libertycreativesolutions.com; s=libertycreativesolutions; k=rsa-sha256; p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQD1ixExNc94dMULg3MTGwPkCOxMh1fW5qV793HlNFeIgD83UYO//aPUcY+j2+KkpOvBJixT05X0W+OJrNm35fKesjFuLOUrZPDPEXTXxYLz3B0++0CVrF4aX2JvXkpbn" "WSQo76HkxWJfYORn3aNewu9m/C7T020np4bMZF7Cdvk4wIDAQAB"
```

`s=` in `DKIM-Signature` header represents the selector which is `libertycreativesolutions` but `s=` in the DNS entry represents Service Type which is something different. So remove `s=libertycreativesolutions;` from your DNS entry. `g=` and `d=` are also not needed there.

Comment: Thanks for the help that fixed it but now I am getting  dkim=neutral (no key)

Comment: I was able fixed it and now everything is working fine